# AVR SPI slave first byte problem

Tags: microcontroller, avr, spi, atmega328p, avr-gcc

I have written a simple [SPI slave](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/atmel-2585-setup-and-use-of-the-spi_applicationnote_avr151.pdf) on an [ATMEGA328PB](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001906A.pdf).  It mostly works, however, I can't seem to get the first byte to be what I want.  The difference between the first, second, and all other attempts is also confusing me.

The master pulls the SS line low, waits 500us, then clocks out 15 '0xFF' followed by a '0x00', waits another 500us, then releases the SS.  Simultaneously the AVR responds with its 'payload'.

```
#define F_CPU 8000000L

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define togbit(port,bit) (port) ^= (1 << (bit))  // XOR

// SPI variables
volatile uint8_t received = 0;
volatile uint8_t cnt = 0;
volatile uint8_t incoming[16] = {0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA};
volatile uint8_t payload[16] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO";

uint8_t spiCom(uint8_t data)
{
    SPDR0 = data; // Put current 'payload' into outgoing buffer
    return SPDR0;  // return incoming byte
}

ISR(SPI0_STC_vect)
{
    incoming[received] = spiCom(payload[cnt]);  // Transfer a byte

    if (incoming[received] == 0xFF) // start clocking out data when receiving 0xFF padding
    {
        cnt++;
        received++;
    }

    if (received >= 16 || incoming[received] == 0x00)  // reset array position counters if buffer overflows or received NULL
    {
        received = 0;
        cnt = 0;
    }
}

void initSPI(void)
{
    volatile char IOReg;  // Ignore compiler warnings about me...I'm needed to clear a flag
    DDRB |= (1<<PINB4);  // Set PB4(MISO) as output
    SPCR0 |= (1<<SPIE)|(1<<SPE);  // Enable SPI Interrupt and Slave Mode with SCK = CK/4

    // Clear SPIF bit in SPSR by accessing the SPI registers
    IOReg = SPSR0;
    IOReg = SPDR0;

    sei();
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0x00; // all of PORTB is input
    initSPI();
    DDRB |= (1<<PINB0);  // LED I/O is output

    SPDR0 = 0xC8;  // pre-load something identifiable into SPI buffer

    while (1) 
    {
        togbit(PORTB, PINB0);  // Blink LED while waiting for SPI interrupt
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

The first attempt at communication, the master receives:
0xC8,A,B,C,D...etc.

The second attempt at communication, the master receives:
0x00,A,B,C,D...etc.

The third and **all subsequent** communications, the master receives:
A,A,B,C,D...etc.

These signals were verified by my logic analyzer.

I can almost accept how the first attempt goes, since 0xC8 is what I pre-load the SPDR register with (as a test).  That said, I still found this behavior unexpected, so I must be misunderstanding something in the SPI section of the AVR's [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001906A.pdf).

I cannot wrap my head around what is happening after that.  If my misunderstanding has to do with the order with which the SPDR register (buffer?) is handled during communication, I still can't figure out the difference between the second and third (and all subsequent) communications.

I've read just about every SPI on AVR tutorial I could find, but can't figure out where I am going wrong.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in your question already. **Simultaneously** being the key word.

Interrupt is called on RX complete, which is when the a byte from master has already been received. This must then also mean a byte from slave has **already been sent**, and your code sets up the next byte to be sent.

You have to set up the first byte to be sent before the communication starts.